# Entity Framework 6 deadlock on multiple inserts with the same context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I do three inserts in my WCF service. Two of them inside another library [class library project] and finally one inside the service itself. I use the same context for all 3 inserts so that I can roll back all 3 if the 3rd fails for example.

My DBContext is set up based on unity and dependency injection:

```
[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Dependency, RegisterDependency(typeof(EmployeeEntities))]
public EmployeeEntities EmployeeDb { get; set; }
```

And here's how my code looks like for performing inserts.

```
using (TransactionScope tr = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel=System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}))
            {
            using (DbContextTransaction dbTransaction = EmployoeeDb.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
library.insertOne(EmployeeDb)
library.insertTwo(EmployeeDb)
EmployeeDb.Add(something); EmployeeDb.SaveChanges()
```

Now everything works fine if I call my service sequentially. However when I simulate a load test, introduce some concurrent calls, the service starts to fail.

Here's the error I see on Traces:An error occurred while updating the entities. See the inner exception for details:
Transaction (ProcessId 128) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Adding an important point. I do some selects in my class library to compare against existing data. Those selects I am guessing are taking a lot of time. I don't have the transactionscope readuncommited on my libraries. I just pass the context, do my selects and inserts with it.

> Blockquote